# Why is this argument required to outlive the function body, even though it is not referenced again?

Tags: rust

When I `cargo check` this function:

```rust
// this does not work
pub async fn verify_passcode<'a>(pass: Passcode, hash: PasswordHash<'a>) -> Result<bool> {
    Ok(task::spawn_blocking(move || argon2_verify(pass, hash)).await?)
}
```

I receive the following error informing me that hash` escapes the function body, even though is not referenced again after the closure takes ownership of it:

```rust
error[E0521]: borrowed data escapes outside of function
  --> src/auth.rs:31:8
   |
30 | pub async fn verify_passcode<'a>(pass: Passcode, hash: PasswordHash<'a>) -> Result<bool> {
   |                              --                  ---- `hash` is a reference that is only valid in the function body
   |                              |
   |                              lifetime `'a` defined here
31 |     Ok(task::spawn_blocking(move || argon2_verify(pass, hash)).await?)
   |        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |        |
   |        `hash` escapes the function body here
   |        argument requires that `'a` must outlive `'static`
```

As the compiler suggests, the issue can be resolved by giving `hash` a lifetime of `'static`:

```rust
// this works
pub async fn verify_passcode(pass: Passcode, hash: PasswordHash<'static>) -> Result<bool> {
    Ok(task::spawn_blocking(move || argon2_verify(pass, hash)).await?)
}
```

...but I would have expected that a lifetime of `'a` would be sufficient, and `'static` seems like a poor solution at best.

1. How does `hash` escape the function when it is not referenced again after the scope of the closure or the blocking thread? Why is `'a` not a sufficient lifetime?
2. How can I resolve this error without resorting to a `'static` lifetime, which feels wrong?

Full example:

```rust
use anyhow::Result;
use argon2::{
    password_hash::{rand_core::OsRng, PasswordHash, PasswordHasher, PasswordVerifier, SaltString},
    Argon2,
};
use tokio::task::{self};

type Passcode = [u8; 32];

// this does not work– 'hash' escapes the function body
pub async fn verify_passcode<'a>(pass: Passcode, hash: PasswordHash<'a>) -> Result<bool> {
    Ok(task::spawn_blocking(move || argon2_verify(pass, hash)).await?)
}

fn argon2_hash<'a>(pass: Passcode) -> Result<PasswordHash<'a>> {
    let salt = SaltString::generate(&mut OsRng);
    let argon2 = Argon2::default();

    Ok(argon2.hash_password(&pass, &salt).unwrap())
}

fn argon2_verify(pass: Passcode, hash: PasswordHash) -> bool {
    Argon2::default().verify_password(&pass, &hash).is_ok()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does hash escape the function when it is not referenced again after the scope of the closure or the blocking thread? Why is 'a not a sufficient lifetime?

`spawn_blocking` does not have [scoped](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scope.html) semantics, so as far as the type system / compiler is concerned it just goes to live its live independent of the current function.

It's actually `spawn_blocking` itself which requires a static lifetime:

```rust
pub fn spawn_blocking<F, R>(f: F) -> JoinHandle<R> ⓘ
where
    F: FnOnce() -> R + Send + 'static,
    R: Send + 'static
```

Nothing actually requires waiting on the handle, which is [the cause for the original removal of scoped threads](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/24292), before the API was rethought in a way which works ([but not for async tasks](https://wishawa.github.io/posts/thread-scoped-async/)).

> How can I resolve this error without resorting to a 'static lifetime, which feels wrong?

Unless argon2 has an owned version of `PasswordHash`, I think all you can do is move whatever that's created from inside the task, and create the PasswordHash in there.